# java Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed

Tags: jna

Пытаюсь написать glowexp для ксго (Библотеки https://github.com/Jonatino/Java-Memory-Manipulation и https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

Ошибка типо нет прав, уже все посмотрел не нашел как исправить это

[Тут ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrbNa.jpg)

[Ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNhsl.jpg)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

`ReadProcessMemory`, `WriteProcessMemory` и `OpenProcess(..PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS)` можно сделать только приложению с правами администратора! То есть что бы `access violation` не было, процесс должен иметь права взаимодействия с другими процессами.

Comment: А как дать ему права?

Comment: Запустить IDE с из под админа, иногда помогает.

Comment: У меня не сработало, но я уже решил проблему